# What is the difference between O(n + k log n) and O(n log n)

Tags: time-complexity, runtime, big-o, complexity-theory

In big O notation of time complexity in algorithmic analysis, is O(n + k log n) the same as O(n log n) if k is larger than n? I am not entirely sure about this.

Comment: The difference is that the first isn't valid. There are no constant factors in Big-O notation.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Given the context, `k` probably isn’t a constant factor. Even if it were, this doesn’t make it *invalid* (it’s totally valid!), just trivially simplifiable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you mean by N+KlogN.  I'm used to seeing K used as a subset of N, for example "the top Kth set of items in N" which for large N it is common to simply return the top K items in N because then the Big-O time is NlogK which is much faster than NlogN (because K is a smaller number).

If you literally mean N+KlogN, then that would be more complex than simply NlogN as K adds to the number.  For example, as K goes to zero you simply end up with NlogN, otherwise you get a greater than NlogN, which I hope would be obvious is more complex.

I hope that does something to answer the question.  I confess I feel like I might be missing the point here and if so I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

No, in the specific case you’re mentioning these are not the same. For example, consider this algorithm: given an array of length N and a number K ≥ N, do a linear scan over the array, then do K binary searches on the array. How much work is done here? Well, the linear search takes time O(N), and the K binary searches collectively take time O(K log N), so the total work done is O(N + K log N).

However, the work here is *not* O(N log N). Since K can be arbitrarily large, the value of K log N can exceed the value of N log N by an arbitrary amount. A different way of seeing this: a bound of O(N log N) means that the runtime depends purely on N and not on K. But that can’t be the case here, since cranking K way, way up definitely increases the runtime, independently of what N is.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I assume it as N + (K log N) where N is total count and K is the subset count. Now assuming K is very small compared to N (possibly a constant to get top K numbers from varying N) it reduces to linear time.

For example, to get top 100 items from array of 10000 elements

10000 + (100 * log (10000) base 2) = 10000 + 1300

Now when N is 20000, k log n changes to 1400

So as N increases linearly, the k log n increases in logarithmic manner reducing the overall complexity to linear.

O(n + (k log n))  is approximately O(n)